# Wordpress widget with xml asynchronous integration

Tags: api, xml-parsing, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a task to do where I need to make calls to an external xml api to fetch data for an event calendar in the sidebar of a site. The date will be changed with JavaScript and then i need to make another call to refresh the data. Can somebody give me an idea about how to cleanly set up an action or function somewhere that I can direct an Ajax action to? It's easy to set up a widget with the correct HTML etc but where does the Ajax connect to? Ideally when the content initially loads on the page it would use the same function that the post is going to use to generate the HTML on the server side.

Any tips would be appreciated. This is an xml api...no option for json or jsonp so credentials including a token and user I'm assuming will have to go somewhere in my widget, something like a proxy function?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you're asking about making cross-domain AJAX requests, AKA the "same origin policy."

The same origin policy prevents document or script loaded from one origin from getting or setting properties of a document from a different origin (domain). See http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/same-origin.html for a more detailed description of the policy.

See [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) for a good description of the options available to circumvent this limitation.

The short answer is that unless you have control over the domain to which you're making AJAX requests, your best bet is probably to set up a simple proxy that lives in the same domain where your AJAX is running, which will forward requests to the destination. Doing a google search on "simple AJAX proxy" will get you a host of results, including pre-built proxies in a variety of languages.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a way to create a proxy within a wordpress plugin